# Knex client undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

Was hoping to see if anyone knows why this error is occurring? I am trying to deploy an app to digital ocean and everything was going well until this.

```
emphasized text/home/user/koala/server/node_modules/knex/lib/knex.js:33
  if (arguments.length === 0 || !config.client && !config.dialect) {
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
    at Knex (/home/user/koala/server/node_modules/knex/lib/knex.js:33:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/koala/server/db/connection.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/koala/server/components/account/accountController.js:1:82)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: have a close look at env variables.

Comment: Thank you Fazal. The issue was it could not find the correct environment because I had an || operator determining production or development. I cleared one of them and it worked. Thanks for the help!